# How to link/connect callbacks, observers, and objects

Tags: c, callback, producer-consumer

I am new to C and trying to figure out to implement the following:

1. I have an array of callbacks/observers for some event
2. Each callback will do something different with the event/data in the callback
3. How do I perform a "this->", "self" in python, or "bind" with the callback.
4. This is all performed in a multi threaded environment, producer/consumer style of sharing data.
5. How to handle multiple consumers of the same type? For example, in C++ I have used classes with condition variables as members, which works because the callback is tied to the object. But in C, how would I do this? So in the example below, how would I notify obj_1, and obj_2 that there is an event to be proccesed. Each could have a queue or buffer of events, but then it goes back to #3, how do link the queue/buffer to the callback?

Here is a simple example of the real implementation

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
/* Different objects, have different data members and implementations */
struct MyObject {
  int data;
};
struct MyOtherObject {
  double data;
};
void MyObjectCallback(int event, struct MyObject* o) {
  /* On an int event MyObject does something with the data */
  o->data *= event + event;
}
void MyOtherObjectCallback(int event, struct MyOtherObject* o) {
  /* On an int event MyOtherObject does something with the data */
  o->data = sqrt(o->data) * event;
}

typedef void (*callback)(int);
/* All the callbacks for an "int" event */
static callback all_callbacks[10] = {NULL};

int main() {
  struct MyObject obj_1, obj_2;
  obj_1.data = 1;
  obj_2.data = 2;
  struct MyOtherObject obj_3;
  obj_3.data = 3;
  /* How do I link the MyObjectCallbacks to all_callbacks?  */

  /* Somewhere an "int" event has occured, notify all callbacks */
  int actual_event = 42;
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    /* This doesnt work cause all_callbacks has no idea of MyObjects */
    if (all_callbacks[i] != NULL) all_callbacks[i](event);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do this in C when you know C++? There is no `this` per-se in C.

Comment: This could be done with a linked list of callback functions to engage. As C functions do not have intrinsic context you'll often see these functions given an arbitrary `void*` context pointer when registering them with the observer mechanism.

Comment: @tadman learning c, working on some work code bases all in c.

Comment: Since C is a primitive and functional not an objective language, you have to do it all primitively. If you want to use a queue structure you have to create it from scratch or get it from another one. Can you share an example from C++ about what you wanna do exactly?